# Adding objects to an array on submitting a form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to add objects one by one to an array in state when I submit a form but I only get one object in the array, here's a code snippet for that:

**MY STATE**

```
state = {
    comments: [],
    text: ""
  };
```

**HANDLE FORM SUBMIT**

```
 handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const arr = [];
    arr.push({ name: this.state.text, id: Math.random() });
    this.setState({ comments: arr, text: "" });
  };
```

**RENDER METHOD**

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })}
          />
          <ul>{this.renderComments()}</ul>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because every time handleSubmit is called the `arr` is initialized to an empty array,Remove the arr array and on submit spread the comments array and add the item

```
 handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
   comments: [...this.state.comments,
   { name:this.state.text, id: Math.random() }
   ],text: ""});
 };
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-yonath-ju5oh)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because every time you run handleSubmit function you create new empty array, push one new comment onto it and then replace whole comments field in state with it. To make it work just read from state what currently is held in comments array and push onto it instead of creating new one.

Comment: I agree with you, this line `const arr = [];` needs to be updated to be `const arr =  this.state.arr`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to replace values in everytime, handle submit:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    arr.push({ name: this.state.text, id: Math.random() });
    this.setState({ ...state, comment: [...state.comments, { name: this.state.text, id: Math.random() }] });
  };
```